# Discretionary Access Control (DAC) for sockets?

Tags: settings

How to add DAC for sockets in config.fs?

https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/filesystem

after making user and group of non-root, using the config.fs changes as mentioned in the page, with non-root user our application creating a problem with network I/O error so read we have config for sockets as well but no example is given in that page.

Anybody has an example of adding sockets in config.fs page.

Comment: What is the specific difficulty you are querying about? I admit you have driven my attention to the page now 3 times. Is this the ultimate goal?

Comment: @wbogacz after making user and group of non-root, using the config.fs changes as mentioned in the page, with non-root user our application creating a problem with network I/O error so read we have config for sockets as well but no example is given in that page